# ui.ButtonSet only working for owner account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**EDIT - I scrapped my original question because I was able to narrow down my problem to a simpler script. If I use the getUi module w/ my account it is totally fine. However, if another user does it, they get no result. if I run this code through the script editor as an anonymous user, I get no results.

```
 function onEdit(){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var prompt = ui.prompt('Type in text?');
    var text = prompt.getResponseText();
  Logger.log(text);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#properties), Use the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to fetch the original XKCD RSS feed then use a standard JavaScript regular expression to make the substitutions we need. Finally, wrap the edited feed in a TextOutput object and set the MIME type to RSS.

To see this in action, publish the script as a web app, making sure to allow anonymous access (since your RSS reader will be visiting it as an anonymous user). Then add the URL of the service to your RSS reader or just visit it directly in a web browser.

```
function doGet() {
var feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://xkcd.com/rss.xml').getContentText();
feed = feed.replace(
/(&lt;img.?alt="(.?)".*?&gt;)/g,
'$1' + new Array(10).join('&lt;br /&gt;') + '$2');
return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}
```

Note:
The button will still run under the users permission. If its anonymous it wont run if it needs any api permission (like reading the spreadsheet) since there is no user. For non anonymous users, you need to add a menu item that will trigger the google permission dialog. After the user approves it will be able to click the image button.